# OAuth issues with Google App Engine And Google Apps Script integration

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth, google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am trying to use Google Apps Script in Google Spreadsheet and have an OAuth issues.

The Spreadsheet and Google App application are both protected by Oauth provided by Google as I am using Google Apps for Business.

Below is the script I am using. It gives me the oauth dance but fails to invoke the URL and retruns with a 302 response.

Not sure what to do next. have tried setting auth callback hadler and everything but did not get far. I also have `ScriptProperties` being set for key and secret (not seen below). Also the scope is not set as App Engine indicates that OAuth is for the entire app.

I get a 302 response at the end of this, after Google App Engine telling me that an app is requesting access. It also indicates that appspot.com is an external provider

```
var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("google");

oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://<blah>.appspot.com/_ah/OAuthGetAccessToken");

oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://<blah>.appspot.com/_ah/OAuthGetRequestToken");

oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://<blah>.appspot.com/_ah/OAuthAuthorizeToken?hd=<blah.com>");

oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey(consumer_key);

oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret(consumer_secret);

var requestData = {
  "method": "GET",
  "oAuthServiceName": "google",
  "oAuthUseToken": "always"
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestData);
```

Comment: A 302 response is a redirect. What makes you think this is an error?

Comment: I wouldn't exactly say its an error .. According to the docs and the posted material , the OAuth actions above are all that is needed to get a OAth working on Google App Engine ..except that it is not working... not sure what to do next  to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the consumerKey and consumerSecret on AppEngine api's.  AppEngine is not part of the authorization/configuration used for Google Apps for Business.  Try without them and revoke the permissions granted already or change the name (from "google") to something else.